# What does fail_silently do in send_mail() django?

Tags: django

I have read the documentation of send_mail() but the purpose of fail_silently is not clear yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As qouted by @Nifled, fail_silently() will raise an exception from smtplib.
I will explain it by quoting an example:
Assume your web app sends an email to a user who submits a feedback every time.
If fail_silently() is set to False while DEBUG mode is set to False or True you will get a very ugly error page(although useful in the beginner stages) which you might not want to show to your user and hence fail_silently()=True comes to your rescue.
Hope now it's clear!!.

Comment: This answer is phrased in the way like failing silently is a good thing - it's not. You should always log all errors, otherwise you'll not know about non-working functionality, or miss the important debugging information. Use try-except and do a logging.exception in the except block.

Answer (score 2):

According to Django docs:

> A boolean. If it’s False, send_mail will raise an smtplib.SMTPException.

So basically, if it's true, you'll get no log or error of a failed sent email.

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail).

Comment: Thanks,I understood it now.